# Path.Combine игнорирует первый аргумент

Tags: c#

Есть переменная folder, в которой записан путь до папки приложения, его значение - `D:\Programming\C#\SKProCH's Launcher\bin\Debug\`. В другой переменной присваивается следующее значение - `Path.Combine(folder, @"/libraries/", @"anyfile.ajr")`. Если мы посмотрим на значение этой переменной, то увидим: `/libraries/anyfile.ajr`.
Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уберите слэши из `@"/libraries/"`. По крайней мере - передний. `Path.Combine` думает, что второй параметр - это абсолютный путь.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_System_String_

> If `path2` or `path3` is also an absolute path, the combine operation
>   discards all previously combined paths and resets to that absolute
>   path.
>
> Если `path2` или `path3` является абсолютным путем, предыдущие
>   параметры не учитываются.